# How to find if one column value exist in another column

Tags: excel

How do I find if column A values matches with any values in column G
There are more values in column G than column A

Please Help!

Ive been tasked with finding if "employee id" (column A) match with any values "other-employee id" (column G). More values in column G than A

Comment: VLOOKUP, MATCH and COUNTIF could all do this.

Comment: `=countif(G:G, A1)` and copy down. If it's greater than 0, then A1 value is in column G